# ASP.NET MVC jquery autocomplete with value and text field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

controller

```
public ActionResult Search(string id)
{
     id= Request.QueryString["term"];         
     var routeList = db.Movies.Where(r => r.Title.Contains(id))
                   .Take(5)
                   .Select(r => new { id = r.MovieID, label = r.Title, name = "MovieID" });
     return Json(routeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:

```
<input type="hidden"   id="MovieID"  name="MovieID" />
<input type="text" id="SelectedMovie" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $("#SelectedMovie").autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           $.ajax({
              url: "/Transaction/Search", type: "POST", dataType: "json",                        
              data: { id: request.term }, 
              success: function (data) {
              response($.map(data, function (item) {                                
                return { label: item.label, value: item.id }; //updated code
               }));
             }
         });
     },
     select: function (event, ui) {
         $("#MovieID").val(ui.item.value);
         $("#SelectedMovie").val(ui.item.label);
         return false;
     }
  });
</script>
```

I have some kind of videostore app. When I go to rent a movie I need a combobox with movies which I can select by using autocomplete.
Also requirement is that only ID (value) is saved to the databas and not the text itself.

EDIT: here is the full working exqample

Comment: 1st please tell me if my controller is OK ? when I run it manually I get no results , search term (id) is passed as null ??

Comment: I would expect to pass `request.term` _NOT_ `request.id` to the `$.ajax()` call.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are passing only a string to the `Search()` function on the server side, the `data` elements that you are passing via the `$.ajax()` call need to be changed.

```
public ActionResult Search(string id)//I think that the id that you are passing here needs to be the search term. You may not have to change anything here, but you do in the $.ajax() call
{
      id= Request.QueryString["term"];

      var routeList = db.Movies.Where(r => r.Title.Contains(id))//this is a text filter no?
                        .Take(5)
                        .Select(r => new { id = r.MovieID, label = r.Title, name = "MovieID" });
      return Json(routeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

```
$("#MovieID").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Transaction/Search", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            //original code
            //data: { searchText: request.id, maxResults: 10 },
            //updated code; updated to request.term 
            //and removed the maxResults since you are not using it on the server side
            data: { id: request.term },

            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    //original code
                    //return { label: item.FullName, value: item.FullName, id: item.TagId }; 
                    //updated code
                    return { label: item.label, value: item.label, id: item.id };
                }));
            },
        select: function (event, ui) {
                //update the jQuery selector here to your target hidden field
            $("input[type=hidden]").val(ui.item.id);
        }
        });
    },
});
```

---

Let me know if this works/helps!

Comment: OK this works. but instead of showing ID in same field i need to save it in hidden one. please help

Comment: @Jalle, my answer has been updated to reflect the changes that you need. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: @JoeFletch, everything is working as expected except that the event is not triggered when I select the value on the drop. I have placed my debugger inside the 'select: function (event, ui) {' but the compiler never reaches there. Do you have any idea concerning what might be wrong?

Comment: @LuisGouveia not a clue. I do not have any of your code posted, so I do not know your circumstances.

Comment: @JoeFletch thank you but I figured it out myself a couple of days after my comment. I am sorry that I didn't tell you.

Answer (score 4):

Your `.ajax()` call is not specifying in an `id`.  it's not in your `data{}` object, nor is it in a `querystring` as part of the  url parameter (either approach would work).

Hence the null value in your Action method.

Anyway, you are immediately over-writing the method's id argument with `Request.QueryString["term"]`. Why to do that??

> Instead of asking Request for the 'term' *inside* the method,you just
>   bind that to the `Action` method as a parameter itself like below :

```
public ActionResult Search(string term)
{
    var routeList = db.Movies.Where(r => r.Title.Contains(term))
            .Take(5)
            .Select(r => new { id = r.MovieID, label = r.Title, name = "MovieID" });
    return Json(routeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should use the following return value from your function:

```
return { label: item.title, value: item.id };
```

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) you have to return objects with `label` and `value` properties (no `id` property). The label is what the user sees, the value is what's posted to the server.

Second, you pass a `searchText` and `maxResults` in the Ajax call, so your action method should have two parameters: `public ActionResult Search(string searchText, int maxResults)`.

Can you apply these changes and see if it works?

Comment: Hadn't even noticed that one. When the property names differ it definitely isn't going to work.